# all colors rendering black in blender

Tags: rendering, animation, 2d

can not find what small insignificant thing that I messed up, but I'm working on a 2d animation and I have two layers that are rendering all colors black. I'ved tried every answer on the first forty pages of google and duckduckgo forum answers. all colors were made with the grease pencil. I make animation pretty often and this is not an issue. I only have four layers to the animation. I might've changed something. I make a few animations a week with no issue.

Comment: Share your file?

Comment: hopefully this is everything. I've went through and checked and unchecked a few things so it'll prolly look wild.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/17msFEnTrAMPbdjqchGoPbkNWkwCW1v_Y/view? usp=sharing

Comment: Sorry for not specifying. I meant your blend file. I didn't want an export, as that might not show us everything we need to see. Also, the customary way of sharing is to use Blend-Exchange. https://blend-exchange.com/